# why I can't hook a ie

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, windows-xp, hook

I want to trace all the mouse and keyboard action in IE.
So I write a hook, 
but I found that the hook can't work.
when I hook the IE, and make any action on IE, the IE crashed.

the step is as following.

step.1:

```
g_hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)CallWndProcHtmlHook, g_hInstHookDll, id);
```

step.2:

```
LRESULT CallWndProcHtmlHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

in winxp, sometimes, it is ok.
but it never workded in win7( win7,32bits, with IE8)

Answer (score 0):

I depends a bit on what you wanna do. If you want to have a tool to track user interaction with some kind of browser-based experiment (like a behavioral experiment or for market research) you might be well suited not with a native C++ application that interacts with the IE via hooks, but with a .NET (C# or C++/CLI) programm that makes use of the WebBrowser Control. All of the Windows Forms power would be at your fingertips and - with ease - you can subscribe all of the events thrown by the control, such as MouseMove, MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseClick, MouseDoubleClick, KeyDown, KeyUp, KeyPress - anything you might want.

Of course, this might not be what you want, if you'd want to track user interaction secretly, for it would be unlikely that a user prefers your browser over any of the known ones.

Comment: it is just a auto test tool, like imacro.